# Default style of HTML Componenets

Tags: css, html, cordova, html-components

I just want to compare the default style of all the HTML(4&5) elements, eg: textbox, selectbox, textarea etc... in different browsers.

For example:-

The HTML text type input style is different in Windows Firefox and Ubuntu Firefox Also There is difference in Chrome and Firefox,

My Actual requirement is :-

I am going to develop a mobile application with help of html5 and phonegap. If I didn't added any css to my page all the html components will take their default style(browser specific or platform specific). I just want to compare that(Android default browser and iPhone default browser etc...).

Any one have idea about these default styling ?

Comment: From what i understand, you want to compare all default browser static css styles attached to every html tag?   I think there are no such documentation, but that its a lot of reading on the different browser developer documentations.  However if there is such a site which will inform about the different default styles i would like to know it aswell.

Comment: check w3c docs of HTML4 and HTML5. I am sure there will be the list of default css properties applied to each element.